# Positioning Logo with Border

Tags: html, css, positioning

im trying to turn a design into code with html and css, but im stumped at a part in the hero section. What's the best way to position this logo with the border that stops around it.

attached is an image of the design i am trying to re-create

[image: refer to this image]

Comment: Please include the (minimal) CSS and HTML that you are using.  Also indicate how th is image is different from how you expected it to appear.

Comment: please explain further about what you want based on the image. And show us what you've done so far then we will help. We can't just imagine your code

Answer (score 3):

you can use before and after classes as

`::before` and `::after` then add **border and position** it on the top of the corner left and right.

```css
*{
  margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  font-family: Arial , Helvetica;
}
.banner-container{
  min-height: 600px; height: 100vh; background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(60, 53, 39, 0.6), rgba(60, 53, 39, 0.7)), url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/2015972/pexels-photo-2015972.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=affection-baby-child-2015972.jpg&fm=jpg"); background-position: center; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.banner-wrap{
  margin: 0 auto; max-width: 960px; height: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;
}
.banner-box{
  border-bottom: solid #A58758 4px; border-left: solid #A58758 4px; border-right: solid #A58758 4px; width: 500px; display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; position: relative; padding: 50px; margin-top: 100px;
}
.banner-box::before{
  content: "";
  width: 127px;
  border: solid #A58758 2px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: -4px;
}
.banner-box::after{
  content: "";
  width: 127px;
  border: solid #A58758 2px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  right: -4px;
}
.banner-box img{
  position: absolute; top: -135px; padding: 5px;
}
.banner-box h2{
  color: #fff; font-size: 2.5rem;
}
.banner-box h1{
  color: #fff; margin: 5px 0; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 400; font-size: 3.8rem; letter-spacing: .4rem;
}
.banner-box h3{
  color: #A58758; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 2.3rem; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: .6rem;
}
a{
  background: #A58758; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; padding: 15px 25px; position: absolute; bottom: -25px; letter-spacing: .1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-container">
  <div class="banner-wrap">
    <div class="banner-box">
      <img src="https://www.thorndalemanors.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/thorndale-footer.svg">
      <h2>Refined Luxury</h2>
      <h1>Singles</h1>
      <h3>In Brampton</h3>
      <a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

check its working properly

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

- Wrapper element (`.box-border`) with two children: `.box-border__top` & `.box-border__img`
- Put a  border on `.box-border` but no top border
- For the top border, use `.box-border__top` consisting of three elements:

  - `.box-border__top:before`: a line
  - `.box-border__img`: the logo, aligned in the center
  - `.box-border__top:after`: a line
- To add spacing around the image, use `.box-border__content`  with `padding: 5em`

```css
body {
  background: url(https://www.goodfreephotos.com/albums/vector-images/farm-landscape-illustration-vector-graphics.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.box-border { /* All side borders by the top */
  border: .5em solid brown;
  border-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.box-border__top { /* Align the image & borders */
  display: flex;
}

.box-border__top:before,
.box-border__top:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: .5em solid brown; /* Sections of the top image */
}

.box-border__img { /* Center Image */
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 0 -99%;
}

/* Add some padding on the bottom */
.box-border__content {  padding: 5em;  }
```

```html
<div class="box-border">
  <div class="box-border__top">
    <img class="box-border__img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/Android_robot.png" width="100" height="90" />
  </div>
  <div class="box-border__content">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Robogarden_img.png/800px-Robogarden_img.png" width="300" />
  </div>

</div>
```